# Join tables using bridges

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help with MySQL. Db was given to me, and unfortunately I can't alter it's structure in any way.

I need to extract a list of employees that belong to a specific group (e.g. group_id = 2). I'm not very good with joining multiple tables using bridges. Can you please give me a hand with that?

```
+---------------+
|employees      |
+---------------+
|employee_id    |
|FirstName      |
|LastName       |
+---------------+

+-------------------------------+
|employees_department           |
+-------------------------------+
|employee_id                    |
|department_id                  |
+-------------------------------+

+--------------+
|departments   |
+--------------+
|deparmtent_id |
|name          |
+--------------+

+--------------------------------+
|department_groups               |
+--------------------------------+
|group_id                        |
|department_id                   |
+--------------------------------+

+---------------+
|groups         |
+---------------+
|group_id       |
|group_name     |
+---------------+
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: So, just selecting from  department_groups` & `JOIN`-ing the other 3 tables? Seems like a textbook straightforward join, where are you having problems?

Comment: I'm a student doing a part time job, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName       
 FROM department_groups AS dg
 JOIN employees_department AS ed ON (ed.department_id = dg.department_id)
 JOIN employees AS e ON (e.employee_id = ed.employee_id)
 WHERE dg.group_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick: `select * from employees, employees_department, department_groups, groups WHERE employees.employee_id = employees_department.employee_id and employees_department.department_id = department_groups.department_id and department_groups.group_id = groups.group_id and groups.group_id = 2`

Note that if group_id is not an integer this will fail.  You may have to change the last bit `groups.group_id = '2'` instead.